# ignoring file Accounts.framework/Accounts, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386):

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks

sorry for my english. I'm using XCode 4.6 and try to include [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) in my App, which uses Accounts.framework and Social.framework. And after including i got following warning:

```
ignoring file <path-to-sdk>/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Accounts.framework/Accounts,
file was built for unsupported file format
( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 9 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 )
which is not the architecture being linked (i386): 
<path-to-sdk>/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Accounts.framework/Accounts
```

(for Social.framework equal warning)

and after that so much errors in functions that uses this frameworks

I try to compile in i386 arch, couse x64 needs too many changes in my project

Thanks.

PS I add this frameworks in my projects (not physically)

Comment: In x64 sample it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong . By looking towards your log I think you are developing application for OSx  and you are adding the iOS frameworks .

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233

and 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024

Comment: No , You can see in documents :Availability: 
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: `The Social framework lets you integrate your app with supported social networking services. On iOS and OS X, this framework provides a template for creating HTTP requests.` for social framework and `2012-07-17 Updated to support OS X Mountain Lion.` for accounts.framework